# Force prefix EncryptedKey element in Xml Encryption

Tags: c#, xml, encryption

I am currently following the example of msdn [How to: Encrypt XML Elements with Asymmetric Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229746%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

With my changes, I have this code

```
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.EncryptedKey ek = new System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.EncryptedKey();
byte[] encryptedKey = EncryptedXml.EncryptKey(sessionKey.Key, Alg, false);
ek.CipherData = new CipherData(encryptedKey);
ek.EncryptionMethod = new System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncRSA15Url);
ek.Id = "EK-ID001";

//other code logic

SecurityTokenReference str = new SecurityTokenReference(bst);
ek.KeyInfo = new KeyInfo();
ek.KeyInfo.AddClause(str);

dRef1.Uri = "#" + EncryptionElementID[0];
ek.AddReference(dRef1);

dRef2.Uri = "#" + EncryptionElementID[1];
ek.AddReference(dRef2);
```

This generates the following XML element

```
<EncryptedKey Id="EK-ID001" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
    <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            <wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-b72da154-e8c3-4858-9923-2456589ac6fc" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
        </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    </KeyInfo>
    <xenc:CipherData>
        <CipherValue>lW8A7SqeB....</CipherValue>
    </xenc:CipherData>
    <ReferenceList>
        <DataReference URI="#Encrip1"/>
        <DataReference URI="#Encrip2"/>
    </ReferenceList>
</EncryptedKey>
```

But I need force the prefix **xenc** and `KeyInfo` tag with **ds**, like

```
<xenc:EncryptedKey Id="EK-ID001" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
    <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
    <ds:KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            <wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-b72da154-e8c3-4858-9923-2456589ac6fc" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
        </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
    <xenc:CipherData>
        <CipherValue>lW8A7SqeB</CipherValue>
    </xenc:CipherData>
    <xenc:ReferenceList>
        <xenc:DataReference URI="#Encrip1"/>
        <xenc:DataReference URI="#Encrip2"/>
    </xenc:ReferenceList>
</xenc:EncryptedKey>
```

Comment: Am also having similar issue. I need to call web service hosted in Java ESB,. am manually signing the xml and added digital signature. but java doesnt understand the SOAP envelope. have you found any solution?